# Losing All Permissions upon editing List Item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, permissions

I have access to SPD, and have SO permissions in the site collection. (no access to central admin)

In a sub-site I have a list that tracks new-hires. I have workflows that run in the background. One runs on change and creation. The other runs on creation and loops once a day.

For some reason, when I try to add/edit a record in the list the workflows will not start and all my permissions are revoked from the site-collection.

I've tried many different scenarios. I've even added other uses as SO's and had them perform the operations. The Workflows fire off fine and they don't lose any permissions.

Could anyone help me figure out what's going on? Especially why my permissions are being removed?

Let me know if I should be more specific or add any additional information. Thank you.